# Increment a char in C

Tags: c, char, digits

I have a small not understanding with increment a char in c.
let suppose:

```c
char c = 'A';
```

now if I do `c+1`, the value in `c` will be `'B'`. This is fine. 
But why when I do the following:

```c
c = c + argv[1][2]
```

then I got `'r'` in `c` why?

please suppose that the argument is `"in12345"`, then `argv[1][2]` is equal to `1`.

What I am trying to do is for some input, lets say ABCDEF is to receive BDFHJG when I am do it in cyclic manner from the arguments. but I don't understand why the above is not working for me.

why it is not working and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: [www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: How exactly does `'A'` + `'1'` or `'A'` + `'3'` make sense?

Comment: `argv[1][2]` is equal to the *character value* `'1'`, not the integer value `1`.  You’re adding the encoding value for the character (ASCII 49) to `c`.

Comment: @JohnBode Please use the answer section, not the comments section, for answering the question. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> please suppose that the argument is in12345, then argv[1][2] is equal to 1.

No it isn't. It's equal to `'1'`, or (assuming ASCII) 49.

`'A'` (65) + `'3'` (49) = `'r'` (114)

If you want to get the integer `1` from the character `'1'`, you need to convert it. A cast won't help; one way to do this is with some arithmetic magic:

```
char c = 'A';

const int valToAdd = argv[1][2] - '0';
c = c + valToAdd;

// c is now 66, or `'B'`
```

However, this is a bit of a hack, and it will break if `argv[1][2]` is not in the range `'0'` to `'9'`. You can do further research on the best (better?) ways to get an integer from an ASCII numeric digit.

Comment: I check my self with fputc(argv[1][2],stdout) and i got 1

Comment: @JohnD You saw "1" on the screen because that's how ASCII characters are displayed on the screen. That is not the same thing.

Comment: then how can I got 1 and not '1'? even casting to int is not working

Comment: @JohnD (`argv[1][2] - '0'`), but i advise you check to ensure it is a digit character *first*  (`isdigit`). Otherwise that expression makes little sense.

Comment: It sounds like you need to review the difference between a `char`'s integral value (e.g. ASCII code) and the way it's represented on screen (as text). Chucking in a cast won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

The `'1'` is not the number `1` only `49` as it is the ASCII code for the char `'1'`.

So you add not `1` but `49`.

Answer (score 1):

`"in12345"` is a string consisting from characters 'i', 'n', '1', '2', and so on. That is for example '1' is not a number. It is a character. So in this expression

```
c = c + argv[1][2]
```

you actually have

```
c = c + '1'
```

where the character c is added with the internal representation of the character '1' that in the ASCII table has the value `49`

To convert the character '1' to integer value 1 you can write for example

```
c = c + ( argv[1][2] - '0' )
```

or just

```
c += argv[1][2] - '0'
```